# Typing String array lists

Tags: arraylist, types

I am reviewing someone's code. They declared an array like this:

```
List<String> values = new <String> ArrayList();
```

I didn't even know you could do that.  I thought you have to do it like this:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>()
```

Are there any advantages to doing it the first way (the  after new instead of after ArrayList?  It compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in java is actually taking no effects

```
List<String> values = new <String> ArrayList();
```

your list is still a raw-list

in fact you can even do:

```
List<String> values = new <String>ArrayList();
values = new <Integer>ArrayList();
```

is still not defining that the arrayList is holding...

the correct form is:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: That is what I thought.  Thanks.  Why is the syntax even permitted?